# Update user without hashing twice password

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel, bcrypt-ruby

My model:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
self.raise_on_save_failure = false
plugin :validation_helpers
def validate
    super
    validates_format /@/, :email
    validates_presence [:email, :password]
    validates_unique :email
end

def before_save
    super
    self[:password] = BCrypt::Password.create(self[:password])
end
```

end

But when i **update** user, my password hash twice. I know it is because of `before_save` hook, but i want to keep `sequel` validating (validates_presence) real **password**, not result of bcrypt hash (cause `BCrypt::Password.create('')` is not empty)

So i need somehow do next:

1. check if password changed
2. validate real password by `sequel`
3. save bcrypt hash of my password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your work flow. If you want an invalid input to be only caught when trying to update the DB, why not go for something like this:

```
post '/update' do
  ...

  if params[:password] == nil || params[:password].empty?
    password = nil
  else
    password = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
  end

  # I have no idea how this line should really look like in your code
  User.find(param[:id]).set(:password, password)

  ...
end
```

So basically, give it nil if the password field was not sent or empty.

As stated very clearly by iain in the comments:

> [...] you should only be using Sequel to validate data that is or will be held by the database. The real password should be validated by the business logic layer, which is what is happening in this answer.

Comment: thanks, but you `set` to DB hashed password. so Sequel Model will validate hash, not real password, like in case with hooks (`before_save`). your hint is okay, if i need only `validates_presence`, but min/max length we should validate manually too. I don't know is it possible to use Sequel validation helper in this case.

Comment: @bravedick From the list of hooks available [here](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/model_hooks_rdoc.html) it looks like you'd better use `before_create` rather than `before_save`.

Comment: @bravedick I think this is the correct answer, because you should only be using Sequel to validate data that is or will be *held by the database*. The real password should be validated by the business logic layer, which is what is happening in this answer. From [Why Validations?](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html#label-Why+Validations%3F) "Validations are primarily useful for associating error messages to display to the user with specific attributes on the model".

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in class method like this:

```
  if user.password_digest != expected_password
    user = nil
  end
```